# Umbraco Code Library - Version Non-specific

Tags: c#, shared-libraries, umbraco

I've created a code library for use with Umbraco, as you'd expect it does all of the common tasks that I use over and over. I work for a digital agency and we support sites that are built from Umbraco versions (4.5.x onwards).

To date we've always complied the library against the same dlls as we're using for the current project, but this isn't great and we've ended up with lots of different branches, one for each version. Having this many branches is a nightmare and I'm trying to find a solution that has one project that can be used to all versions.

I'm just wondering if anyone can think of or knows a way of having doing this or has any experience in this?

Comment: This all depends on what requirements your library has. If it references the Umbraco libraries specifically then they change so often that this is wise. If the code is all general stuff and is (or can be) 'detached', i.e. not dependent on, the Umbraco types, then the version becomes largely irrelevant.

Comment: Most of the stuff in the library are things like Node extension methods. Having had a look through the Umbraco code again it looks like the Interfaces have stayed the same for many versions. Could be an idea to just reference the interfaces dll and create extension methods for INode and not Node etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you code purely to the `INode` interface then you should be able to create your library independent of the version. `DynamicNode` and `DynamicMedia` both implement `INode`.